# ask for help to install open office on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

I follow the instruction to install the app. in terminal, but it show that '' error processing archive en-us/debs/*.deb (--install):''
Can you help me? Thank you very much.

---

more details:

eric@garden-HP-Compaq:~$ cd /tmp
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i zh-tw/debs/*.deb
[sudo] password for eric: 
dpkg: error processing archive zh-tw/debs/*.deb (--install):
 無法存取壓縮檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
處理時發生錯誤：
 zh-tw/debs/*.deb
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i zh-tw/debs/desktop-integration/*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive zh-tw/debs/desktop-integration/*.deb (--install):
 無法存取壓縮檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
處理時發生錯誤：
 zh-tw/debs/desktop-integration/*.deb
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i en-gb/debs/*.deb
[sudo] password for eric: 
dpkg: error processing archive en-gb/debs/*.deb (--install):
 無法存取壓縮檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
處理時發生錯誤：
 en-gb/debs/*.deb
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ dpkg ?
dpkg：錯誤：欠缺操作選項

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -izh-tw/debs/*.deb
dpkg：錯誤：未知的選項 -z

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i zh-tw/debs/*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive zh-tw/debs/*.deb (--install):
 無法存取壓縮檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
處理時發生錯誤：
 zh-tw/debs/*.deb
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ 
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ ^C
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$

---

I have removed the libre office and then installed the open office that I used in 13.x

Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -izh-tw/debs/*.deb
dpkg：錯誤：未知的選項 -z

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ sudo dpkg -i zh-tw/debs/*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive zh-tw/debs/*.deb (--install):
 無法存取壓縮檔: 沒有此一檔案或目錄
處理時發生錯誤：
 zh-tw/debs/*.deb
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ 
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$ ^C
eric@garden-HP-Compaq:/tmp$

the return is as above.

Please suggest me how to do.

Comment: Instructions can be wrong, what are the exact steps/cammands? Can you copy/pate, and post them.

Comment: It's there something wrong with libre office?

Comment: thanks a lot. I had uninstalled the libre office, then install the open office.

Answer (score 0):

First run the below command,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* #if installed

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Download respective Arch. files,

For 32bit

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.0/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

For 64 bit

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.0/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
tar -xvfz Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz (for 32bit)

tar -xvfz Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz (for 64bit)

cd en-US/DEBS/
dpkg -i *.deb 
cd en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: I just follow this instrustions.